# Unable to output MySQL data to FPDF table

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I've tried the tutorials on fpdf and searched all over for helpful code. And I found what I thought would do the trick here on SO. That said, following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671862/how-to-print-data-from-mysql-into-a-pdf-file-using-php) didn't produce good results. I definitely need help with this.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once '../root_login.php';
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
// Logo
//$this->Image('images/bg_all.jpg',10,6,30);
// Arial bold 15
$this->SetFont('Times','B',20);
// Move to the right
$this->Cell(80);
// Title
$this->Cell(40,10,'B A S E B A L L',0,0,'C');
// Line break
$this->Ln(6);
// Arial bold 15
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$this->Cell(200,10,'LITTLE LEAGUE ROSTERS',0,0,'C');


$this->Ln(20);

}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
// Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
$this->SetY(-15);
// Arial italic 8
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
// Page number
$this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',8);

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT fname, lname 
                    FROM rosters 
                    ORDER BY lname');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $row) {
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'F NAME:', $row['fname']); 
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'L NAME:', $row['lname']);
$pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

You can view the output [here](https://www.dfwit.co/fpdftest1.php)

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? And why are those lines being drawn? Thanks.

Comment: You're not connecting to the database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Then why do I get F NAME & L NAME printed out through the $results? And for the same number of people I have in the db table? I thought what you said was right, initially, so I moved my root_login.php to the working folder. That made zero difference.

Comment: Does root_login contain the connection to the database?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - yes. It's the same credentials I use across my website for connecting. That's why I'm at a loss, because I know that is correct. It just won't output the data. If it wasn't iterating through the $results, that'd make it easy to pinpoint. But it's running through the db table and printing out the right number of F NAME & LNAME. Just not the kiddos' names. Not to mention the crazy lines it's drawing. Another mystery, that.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of the column names? No letter case problems? The lines are coming from the default for `cell`. You should always, in my experience, fully define all of the cell options in FPDF.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I am. And I've even tried $row[0] and $row[1], but that doesn't change the outcome. This is the kind of stuff that kills a day! But I have to get this into pdf. I really don't know what else to do. I hope before the sun sets someone can get me pointed in the right direction and show me some silly mistake I made in that code. I can deal with that.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - This is my first attempt using fdpf. I don't know what you mean by `fully define all of the cell options in FPDF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FPDF you should fully define all cell options and your text for the cell should be in the third position:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'L NAME:'. $row['lname'], 0, 0, 'L'); 
------------------------^
```

Note the concatenation. Then follow up with the border(0 for no border, which should be the default), the next line definition (Putting 1 is equivalent to putting 0 and calling `Ln()` just after. Default value: 0.) and the alignment of the text in the cell.

Comment: I appreciate you, Jay. It's working like a charm now. That's what I get for copy/pasting, and for not paying attention to the fact it wasn't concatenated. I hope I can return the favor one day. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have helped @Landslyde!

Answer (score 1):

Joining the string and doing it with less parameters?

```
  foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'F NAME: '.$row['fname']); 
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,'L NAME: '.$row['lname']);
    $pdf->Ln();
    }
```